# PHP - Create a function that return n-1 times of zeros along with passed parameter

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that would take two parameters

- one could be number itself List item
- another could be the length

and returns like following.

```
myfunction(4, 2) // will be 40
myfunction(3, 1) // will be 3
myfunction(9, 4)  // will be 9000
```

Comment: what is your logic? how do the params relate to the output?

Comment: I’m assuming for `3, 1` you should actually get `3` as result? Then you’re basically looking for `str_pad` with the third parameter set to `'0'` … If you think that special case warrants writing of an explicit wrapper function, well then write one …

Comment: @misorude i have edited the description.

Comment: What would be the expected reult of `10, 1` or `100, 1`?

Comment: @B001ᛦ it should be 10, 1 = 10, and 100, 1 = 100 itself. on the bases of 3, 1 = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you have described the question. I think the following could be helpful for you

```
echo myfunction(4, 2);

function myfunction( $num, $length){
    if( $num > 0 ){
        while( $length > 1 ){
            $num .= 0;
            $length--;
        }
    } else { return null; }
    return $num;
}
```

Comment: let me try with this one first